# How to load the images with class labels from a single directory into Keras model using a dataframe containing filenames and labels?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have two separate folders "train_images" and "val_images". I have all the images inside these two folders. I am doing a categorical classification using DenseNet121 model. I have two different `y_df` (dataframe) for training and validation. I know about `flow_from_directory` but for that I need to create different subforlders inside each "train_images" and "val_images" based on classes.

I am willing to to know if I don't want to create those subforlders and don't use `flow_from_directory`, how do I pass those images into the model? 
I am using Keras with Tensorflow as the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a dataframe that contains the image filenames along with their labels, you can use the newly introduced [`flow_from_dataframe()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/362fe9f8daf556151328eb5d02bd5ae638c653b8/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1015) method which has been exactly defined for this purpose. It takes a Pandas dataframe which contains the filenames of the images in one column and their corresponding labels in another column(s).  <s>It has not been officially released yet, so you need use the latest development version of Keras on the [Keras Github repository](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/). It is expected to be in the next release, though.</s>

**Update:** It has been included in [Keras Preprocessing 1.0.4](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/releases/tag/1.0.4) and [Keras 2.2.3](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.2.3).

Also, there is [a tutorial](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow-from-dataframe-8bd5776e45c1) about this method as well.